# finding dates in a dataframe and getting the index of those dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes say dfOne and dfTwo.

dfOne has a column called Dates. It has every day from 1st Jan 2016 until 1st Jan 2018.

dfTwo also has a column called Dates but say only has 5 dates,

```
  4th Feb 2016
  23rd March 2016
  3rd May 2016
  22nd November 2016
  18th July 2017
```

What is the best way to find the index of each of the dates above in the dataframe dfOne?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need convert them into datetime format

```
df2.Date=pd.to_datetime(df2.Date)
df1.Date=pd.to_datetime(df1.Date)
```

Then we using `isin`

```
df1.index[df1.Date.isin(df2.Date)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`pd.isin` is the way to go if you just need to know the indexes of the intersecting values. If you need the actual `index` values for each entry in your `df2`, you may use index matching

```
df2.set_index('dates').assign(index=df.set_index('dates')['index']).reset_index()
```

For example, MCVE:

```
df          = pd.DataFrame({'dates': ['10/10/2010', '10/11/2010', '10/12/2010', '10/13/2010']}) 
df['index'] = df.index
df2         = pd.DataFrame({'dates': ['10/10/2010', '10/13/2010']})
```

Then, df2 goes from

```
    dates
0   2010-10-10
1   2010-10-13
```

to

```
    dates       index
0   2010-10-10  0
1   2010-10-13  3
```

where 0 and 3 are the respective indexes in `df`.